# Dart Angular replacing provider with mock in unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, angular, mocking, dart, mockito

How can I replace the provider `QuizService` to `QuickServiceMock` in Angular Dart unit testing?

I tried using `addProviders` method but that didn't replace `QuizService` with `QuizkServiceMock`.

It seems `MultipleChoiceQuizComponent` is still using the original class `QuizkService` and not `QuizServiceMock` like I want it to.

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:angular_test/angular_test.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

import '...quiz_service.dart';
import '...multiple_choice_quiz_component.dart';
import '...multiple_choice_quiz.dart';

class MockQuizService extends Mock implements QuizService {}

@AngularEntrypoint()
void main()
{
    group('$MultipleChoiceQuizComponent', () {
        MockQuizService quizServiceMock;
        setUp(() async {
            quizServiceMock = new MockQuizService();
            List<String> mockChoiceList = [
                "incorrect1",
                "incorrect2",
                "correct answer",
                "incorrect3"
            ];
            when(quizServiceMock.getQuiz())
                .thenReturn(
                    new MultipleChoiceQuiz(
                        mockChoiceList,
                        "correct answer",
                        'test question description'
                )
            );
        });

        test('should add "incorrect" css class to incorrect answer', () async {
            NgTestBed bed = new NgTestBed<MultipleChoiceQuizComponent>().addProviders([
                provide(QuizService, useValue: quizServiceMock)
            ]);
            NgTestFixture fixture = await bed.create();
            Element answer = fixture.rootElement.querySelector('.quiz-choice:nth-child(2)');
            answer.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
            bool hasClass = answer.classes.contains('incorrect');
            expect(hasClass, true);
        });
    });

}
```

**multiple_choice_quiz_component.dart:**

```
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';
import 'package:angular2/common.dart';
import 'package:angular2_components/angular2_components.dart';

import '.../quiz/quiz.dart';
import '.../service/quiz_service.dart';

@Component
(
    selector: 'multiple-choice-quiz-component',
    directives: const [materialDirectives, NgFor],
    providers: const [materialProviders, QuizService],
    templateUrl: 'multiple_choice_quiz_component.html',
    styleUrls: const['/app_component.css', 'quiz.css']
)

class MultipleChoiceQuizComponent
{
    String selectedAnswer;
    String description;
    bool correctAnswer = false;
    Quiz quiz;

    MultipleChoiceQuizComponent(QuizService quizService)
    {
        this.quiz = quizService.getQuiz();
    }

    void onSelect(String answer)
    {
        selectedAnswer = answer;
        this.correctAnswer = this.quiz.isAnswer(answer);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you provide `QuizkService` in `MultipleChoiceQuizComponent`? (or in `AppComponent` or `bootstrap(AppCompoennt, [...])`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that service is provided in `MultipleChoiceQuizComponent`

Comment: It doesn't look like `TestBed` supports replacing providers of components.

Comment: Damn, I thought that's what `addProviders` did :(

Comment: To me it looks like `addProviders` allows to provide services at the parent of the tested component.

Comment: What do you mean by the parent? That's a standalone component.

Comment: What I mean is that the `TestBed` can emulate a parent component with providers, but not modify the tested component.

Comment: So there's no way to provide the mock to `MultipleChoiceQuizComponent`'s constructor?

Comment: Sure there is, but it looks like there is no way to override a provider you provide at the same component where you inject it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot override `providers:` in the `@Component` annotation of the widget.

What you can do is move the binding higher in the tree, so that parent (or app bootstrap) provide the binding.

Comment: I've added the component code to my question. I'm not sure what you mean by moving the binding higher.

Comment: Instead of putting `QuizService` in the `providers` on your component, can you put it in the providers in the call to `bootstrap`?

"Higher in the tree" means in the providers of a component that is higher in the DOM tree, or in bootstrap which is the root of the DI tree

Comment: @Nate Too bad it's against Angular best practices https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#webmaindart-bad-alternative

Comment: @Tek - Does each `MultipleChoiceQuizComponent` need it's own instance of a `QuizService`? That is the situation discussed in the guide you linked. If that is the case then I would recommend against mocking QuizService for your tests.

Comment: @Nate Ah, ok. It doesn't need it's own instance... for now. Although I still don't understand how the mock the service to make my test pass.